# Video at last portion not rendered

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, audio

I'm very new to blender.
I've a video of length 11:05 consisting 11082 frames in total. It has video and audio files of same length.
The screenshot of settings is:
[image]

and that of encoding and output setting is:
[image]

when I navigate to the frame 9854 the video is fine as shown below:
[image]

But just after the that frame i.e. frame 9855 the output is as follows:
[image]

I can hear the audio but instead of video that pattern is shown upto the end.
I even checked the output by animating, the end result was same.
How can I get rid of this problem? Where have I missed?

Comment: Is there a reason for the weird 199/12=16.58 fps?

Comment: Well, I don't know. What can I do to solve if that's weird?

Comment: @Reaper I tried to check if you were right about it. But i changed these values to different which caused my videos and audio to become of different length. And the problem of my video showing pattern persists at the same frame regardless of any fps value.